# Show/Hide submenu by click HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a side menu with some menu items.

One menu items can have some submenu items

Here is how I realize this

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav mainmenu">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Calendar")">Calendar</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("SheduleNewAppointment", "Calendar")">- Shedule new appointment</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "PatientDatabase")">Patient Database</a>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Findings")">Findings</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">- All Findings</a></li>
        <li><a href="">- Open Findings</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Controlling")">Controlling</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">- Patients</a></li>
        <li><a href="">- Medical Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="">- Internal Controlling</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Invoices")">Invoices</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">- Receipt of payment</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I need to click on a menu item and it will show submenu items if I click once again it will hide them. How can I realize this?

Comment: You can't do it on a click cause the first element is a link. So clicking on it opens the link. Maybe hover is a better idea?

Comment: Of course you can catch the click event on an anchor tag. To prevent the default action (Redirecting to the href url) you just have to `return false;` in your click handler.

Comment: You want to prevent the basic functionality of a menu item? seems like some futuristic menu ideas

Answer (score 0):

if you use bootstrap then it will be easy to do with it.

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav mainmenu">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a>
 <!-- my changes starts here -->  
 <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Calendar")">Calendar</a>
        <ul class="submenu collapse" id="test">
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("SheduleNewAppointment", "Calendar")">- Shedule new appointment</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "PatientDatabase")">Patient Database</a>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Findings")">Findings</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">- All Findings</a></li>
            <li><a href="">- Open Findings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Controlling")">Controlling</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">- Patients</a></li>
            <li><a href="">- Medical Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="">- Internal Controlling</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Invoices")">Invoices</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">- Receipt of payment</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Answer (score 0):

See here I apply click even on li not on  because on anchor you add a url of other pages, so 22 event not fired on same element.Checkout and if any issue let me know

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.main_wrapper li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).children('.submenu').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.submenu {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  background-color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav mainmenu">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Home ")">Home</a>
  <ul class="main_wrapper">
    <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Calendar ")">Calendar</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="@Url.Action(" SheduleNewAppointment ", "Calendar ")">- Shedule new appointment</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "PatientDatabase ")">Patient Database</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Findings ")">Findings</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">- All Findings</a></li>
        <li><a href="">- Open Findings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Controlling ")">Controlling</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">- Patients</a></li>
        <li><a href="">- Medical Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="">- Internal Controlling</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action(" Index ", "Invoices ")">Invoices</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="">- Receipt of payment</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: When I click on `<li>` it goes to link and not open children items

Comment: Ya but if u click on on anchor tag then it open i checked it

Comment: I mean when you click on calendar then it open related link but when u click on li the sub menu shows .. have you got it .. because we can't perform two thing on same element .